# Нами-котами нельзя управлять!

Tags: орфография

Как правило?

> Нами-котами нельзя управлять!

> Нами, котами, нельзя управлять!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Нами, котами, нельзя управлять!***

Приложение при личном местоимении всегда выделяется запятыми.

См. [пункт 8, справочник Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111).